# Remove WSDL from soapui project without removing test suite [To reduce size of SoapUI project file]

Tags: web-services, testing, soapui

Im having a SOAP UI project which includes both the WSDL and the test suites. But the size is pretty high. Is there a way to remove the wsdl retaining the test suites so that the size would be low. 
I want something like JMeter which just holds the requests and validations.
Is there any way i can do this in SOAPUI.

Answer (score 0):

Now this was fun..

There are two ways through which you can reduce the size of the soapUI project XML.

1) Uncheck the `caches and associated WSDLs locally for offline access and improved performance` option under `preferences>WSDL Settings` like in the below image. This setting has no impact on existing projects just on projects that will be created after this option is checked/unchecked.

[image: soapUI WSDL settings]

Having this option unchecked can significantly reduce the size of the soapUI project. See the image below, both of these projects were created using the same [WSDL](http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?wsdl) and the size is reduced by half. I had another instance where the size reduce from ~400kb to 100 kb after this option was unchecked.

2) Edit the soapUI project xml, this is useful when the project exists and test suites have already been created, which is true in your case. You have to be very careful when editing the project xml as any incorrect edit and you will lose all your work. So before trying this approach **Take a backup of your project**. In your soapUI project remove the `<con:definitionCache/>` element and also remove all the data within the `<con:definitionCache></con:definitionCache>`tags including the tags. This will remove the wsdl content stored locally.